# Calculating time from energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

I am trying to calculate the time of a movement using the energy of the system.
If $$E=\frac{m}{2}\dot{x}^2 + V(x)$$ where $V(x)$ is the potential energy (assuming the potential is time-independent)

Now this can be solved for t, which gives
$$t=\pm \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}(E-V(x))}}dx$$

Now, I would like to calculate for a simple freefall from $h$ height,with $v_0=0$.
Then $E=mgh$ and $V(x)=mgh$ so it's division by zero... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E is the initial mgh, a constant. V is mgx, a function of x.